# How to bring text data from console APP to WPF APP

Tags: wpf, wcf, data-binding, console

I have an client application that brings data from a service/database and can display that information into a console. I'm going to include this application in my WPF project. How do I get that text information to display from a console app to a text app.

I want it to display just in a text block not a console window.

```
console.writeline()
```

this works in the console application to display the information.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var test = new FeedServiceAgent())
    {
        //Register to get events from the FeedService
        test.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;

        test.Subscribe("92", 3);

        //Just wait here to block exit while you get events.
        Console.ReadLine;
    }
}


private static void OnMessageReceived (object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        // This is the main one that you want since CMS data has the info
        // for the skill(s) you are subscribed to.
        if (e.CmsData != null)
        {
            //e.CmsData;

            Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.DirectAgentCallsInQueueInRing.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.SkillStatusColor.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.SkillStatusColorIsBlink.ToString()); 
            // Console.WriteLine ("test");
            Console.WriteLine(e.CmsData.Skill.ExpectedWaitTimeMedium.ToString());
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //    logger.Error(" Exception " + ex);
    //    throw ex;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you have the client app code access?

Comment: I have added the code you requested to the original post